# Why must I manually dispose the Serilog Logger (Sumologic sink) when the dispose option is true?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

I have configured Serilog using (I have attempted this with the dispose option both true and false)

```cs
services.AddLogging(
    loggingBuilder =>
    {
        //Create Serilog logger from AppSettings.json properties.
        _logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();
        loggingBuilder.AddSerilog(_logger, true);
    });
```

Appsettings configuration

```json
    "Logging": {
        "IncludeScopes": true,
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "System": "Warning",
            "Microsoft": "Warning"
        },
        "Debug": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Debug"
            }
        },
        "Console": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information"
            }
        }
    },
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [
            "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
            "Serilog.Sinks.SumoLogic",
            "Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
        ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "System": "Warning",
                "Microsoft": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "Filter": [
            {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                    "expression": "RequestPath = '/api/health'"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "ByExcluding",
                "Args": {
                    "expression": "RequestPath = '/api/info'"
                }
            }
        ],
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "SumoLogic",
                "Args": {
                    "endpointUrl": "todo-setSumoLogEndpointUrl",
                    "sourceName": "sourceName",
                    "sourceCategory": "sourceCategory",
                    "textFormatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Compact.CompactJsonFormatter, Serilog.Formatting.Compact"
                }
            },
            {
                "Name": "Console",
                "Args": {
                    "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console",
                    "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                    "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Debug"
                }
            }
        ],
        "Enrich": [
            "FromLogContext",
            "WithMachineName",
            "WithThreadId"
        ],
```

I am using the Sumologic sink
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.SumoLogic/

I have configured my `DbContext` to use Serilog as well

```cs
private void ConfigureDbContext(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ServiceProvider? provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
    ILoggerFactory? loggerFactory = provider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>();
    services.AddDbContext<ApiDbContext>(options =>
    {
        string? connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApiDatabase");
        // NodaTime allows the use of zoned times.
        options
            .UseNpgsql(connectionString, npgsqlOptions => npgsqlOptions.UseNodaTime())
            // Using snake case avoids the need for quoting tables and columns.
            .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention();
        if (loggerFactory != null)
        {
            options.UseSerilog(loggerFactory);
        }
        if (!IsDevelopment)
        {
            return;
        }
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
            .EnableDetailedErrors()
            .LogTo(Console.WriteLine);
    });
}
```

When running database migrations, I get a fatal exception that causes application startup to fail like:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23505: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"pk_pdt_users\"
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|194_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult(Boolean async, Boolean isConsuming, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions.Migrate(DatabaseFacade databaseFacade)
   at Precisely.Pdx.Api.Web.Startup.UpdateDatabase(IApplicationBuilder app) in /Users/richardcollette/Documents/code/sdm/pdx_api/Precisely.Pdx.Api/Precisely.Pdx.Api.Web/Startup.cs:line 190
   at Precisely.Pdx.Api.Web.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, IApiVersionDescriptionProvider apiVersionDescriptionProvider, ILogger`1 log) in /Users/richardcollette/Documents/code/sdm/pdx_api/Precisely.Pdx.Api/Precisely.Pdx.Api.Web/Startup.cs:line 121
```

If I do nothing else, the error logged by EF, which contains the failed SQL statement is not logged, nor is the resulting exception logged.

Instead, I must keep the Serilog `Logger` as a private field, catch the exception, log it and then manually dispose of the Logger.

```cs
try
{
    UpdateDatabase(app);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.LogError(ex, "Error applying migrations.");
    // This is a fatal error so we dispose the logger to ensure that it's messages are written.
    _logger?.Dispose();
    throw;
}
```

After doing so, the exception is logged as well as the sql error.
[image]

Why does Serilog and/or the sink not write the logs on its own.   Is the provider not disposed in a fatal error scenario?

Answer (score 2):

It's your responsibility to flush the logs before your application ends. See [Lifecycle of Loggers](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Lifecycle-of-Loggers).

You do that by calling `Log.CloseAndFlush()` or by disposing your logger.

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    ConfigureLogging(); // set up Serilog

    try
    {
        Log.Logger.Information("Custom.API Server is starting.");
        var webHost = BuildWebHost(args);
        webHost.Run();

        Log.Logger.Information("Custom.API Server is starting.");
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly.");
        return 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush(); // <##<##<##<##<##<##
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.   I'm not using static Log though.  I am using ASP.NET and DI to setup a log provider.  I know on shutdown that the DI system will call Dispose on IDisposables.   I'm just not sure what happens when the Configure stage of of ASP.NET startup experiences a fatal exception.